# Statistics: question on transformations.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ has a pdf $f(x)=2x$ on $[0,1]$ (and zero otherwise), and let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$. Find a function $g$ such that $g(U)$ and $X$ have the same distribution (behaviour).

Comment: Is this homework? (It sounds like it.) If so, please add the `homework` tab. In any case, you might want to familiarize yourself with the [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform).

Comment: sorry I'm new to the forum. Added.

Comment: Hint: Given a fixed number $t \in [0,1]$, can you figure out the value of $P\{\sqrt{U} \leq t\}$ from the information that $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$?  The answer will, of course, be a function of $t$.  What is $P\{X \leq t\}$? How does it compare to $P\{\sqrt{U} \leq t\}$?  After doing this (hopefully successfully), please do read about probability integral transforms as suggested by cardinal.

Comment: Is there any proof about integral transformation?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33922/what-exactly-is-the-probability-integral-transform