# Intuition behind Probability Integral Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This theorem seems to hold great potential for an intuitive explanation, yet I'm still struggling for it.

Basically, it is saying that if $y = F(x)$, then y would have distribution $Unif[0,1]$. Intuitively, why?

Many thanks!

Comment: What theorem are you speaking of?

Comment: Here is a simple case to ponder. Let's say your computer is capable of generating $\text{Unif}([0, 1])$ random numbers (e.g., this is $\texttt{rand}$ in MATLAB). How would you use this to generate flips of an unfair coin which has probability 0.3 of landing heads and 0.7 of landing tails?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33922/321264

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ were invertible with inverse function $F^{-1}:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$, the event $[Y\leqslant y]=[F(X)\leqslant y]$ would coincide with $[X\leqslant z]$ with $z=F^{-1}(y)$, hence its probability would be $F(z)=y$. A random variable such that $\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y)=y$ for every $y$ in $(0,1)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.