# Probability Integral Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, integral-transforms, uniform-distribution

I just attended an introductory course on Statistics and we came across the following:

> [image]

I know what random variables, the uniform distribution, etc. are but the notation from the proposition above simply eludes me. Would somebody be so kind and explain what the proposition above tells us and how the proof shows what it shows.

Comment: If $U$ is a uniformly distributed random variable (with values in $[0,1]$), then the random variable $X = F^{-1}\circ U$ has the cumulative distribution function $F$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So we can use $\sim$ to indicate either a distribution in general or a distribution function?

Comment: Since the distribution is uniquely determined by its CDF, the two are identified whenever convenient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the Probability Integral Transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33922/what-exactly-is-the-probability-integral-transform)